# Which 3D printer is good for beginners?

Tags: 3d-models, 3d-design, print-quality, desktop-printer

I was looking for some advice on which 3D printers are good for someone who is just getting into 3D printing?

I have been looking at the Anet A8 on ebay but not sure if they are any good or not.

Regards

Comment: the Anet A8 is a great machine. I would highly recommend it.

Comment: I am voting to close this question as being too opinion based. It is extremely open-ended, with very little details to narrow down the search. In general, I think "recommend me a printer"-type questions are not a good fit for this site. The [help center](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) has some information on what types of questions we are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Which printer for a beginner depends far more on the beginner in question than the various printers available.

- If you are comfortable assembling parts and figuring things out a number of options exist.
- If you need a fully-built object, a number of options exist.
- If you require lots of dedicated support, via phone or email, there
  are options.
- If you can ask questions in a forum and get the answers you need (or
  figure things out when you don't and post your answers for others to
  find) there are options.

If you have special/esoteric printing needs, that puts constraints on - if you kinda vaguely want a 3-D plastic printer, but don't really know what you want to use it for the field is wide open.

Comment: Im comfortable with assembling things, especially from an instructions manual. Ive assembled ikea furniture before, so im comfortable with electronics lol. I like to build quadcopters and found that a 3d printer would possibly come in handy for parts. I can also follow instructions and tutorials. I would like something that i can download thingiverse files to and print out for me. And possibly in the future something that i can create something with cad (or other types of 3d printing software) and then print

Comment: So, narrow it down more - how big are your parts likely to be, or what's the largest part you can envision needing to print? Multiply that by a fudge factor,  see where it leads you. Think about things you might or might not want such as multiple extruders, how important speed is to you, whether you can trade accuracy for speed, the size of your piggy bank, and generally the many reasons this fits the "too broad" closure rule at present, and narrow them down, or ask specific questions about them.

Comment: The first item i would like to print is the following... https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1823552

Comment: I would probably prefer quality over speed but i obviously dont want a 3d printer constantly running for a week

Answer (score 2):

A budget would make answering your question alot easier. Do you have any experience with cad/cam software? What are you wanting to do with it? There are many inexpensive 3d printers but your skill level in mechanics/machinery, electronics, programming etc will also help others choose a good option for you. For example, plug and play units are usually more expensive than build your own models. But if you don't have the skill to assemble it the savings wasn't worth it

Comment: Hi Warren, thanks for getting back to me, id say £400 at the maximum for my first machine. I dont have much experience with cad but do work with others who use it so they could probably show me a few things. I use electronics in the work industry that im in and also programming so not much trouble there. And im not shy when it comes to building things so assembly shouldnt be a problem.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. If you want to request clarification from the person who asked the question, you should post a comment - answers are reserved for, well, answers. You will be able to post comments once you achieve 100 reputation.

Comment: Oops, sorry....

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

Anet A8 in Ebay will be probably a kit "do it yourself". Something not easy for starters.

I suggest you buy a cheap and ready to use one. A rebrand of Malyan M200 (Monoprice select mini in U.S., Prima Creator in Europe) or something similar.

**Long answer:**

To select a printer take into account:

- your experience in 3d printing
- your experience in electronics and software.
- your objective: learning, home user, professional?
- if it will be used by children.
- your budget
- the kind of materials you plan to use: PLA only, mainly PLA and ABS, others. PLA only printers are usually a few cheaper because they do not have heat bed.
- availability of support: official support, community size, market penetration.
- build volume

Taken into account previous criteria:

- Anet A8 is usually a Prusa diy kit. As all these kits, it is more
  suitable when there are experience in 3d and hardware/software.
- If the answer to previous questions is "no experience, home user, adults and childrens, medium badget, PLA&ABS, good support, small volume", a printer as Malyan M200 can be a good choice.
- A printer as Flashforge finder differs respect to the previous that it has no heated bed. That means it is more suitable for PLA only.
- (addition of more cases is welcome)

NOTE: This answer is a community wiki to promote multiple editions.